# how to convert base10 numbers into an array

Tags: php

Hi can I get the base10 numbers from an mp3 file in php. I want to store  numbers in an array:

```
<?php
  $filename = "sample.mp3";
  $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
  $fsize = filesize($filename);
  $contents = fread($handle, $fsize);
  fclose($handle);
  for($i = 0; $i < $fsize; $i++) {
    $asciiCharacter = $contents[$i];
    $base10value = ord($asciiCharacter);
    var_dump($base10value)
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: What is the output of var_dump($base10value) ?

Comment: this is just some int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats quite easy, define an array and then load it in the loop

```
<?php
$filename = "sample.mp3";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$fsize = filesize($filename);
$contents = fread($handle, $fsize);
fclose($handle);

$base10array = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $fsize; $i++) {
    $asciiCharacter = $contents[$i];
    $base10value = ord($asciiCharacter);

    $base10array[] = $base10value;

    var_dump($base10value)
}
?>
```

Comment: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

Comment: How many items are you trying to add to this array? Looks like a lot!

Comment: I would say you have exausted your 256Meg of available PHP memory

Comment: the array size is too big its about 9875423

Comment: its only a simple mp3

Comment: Even simple mp3's are quite large files

Answer (score 1):

One line version:

```
 $array = array_map('ord',str_split(file_get_contents("sample.mp3")));
 var_dump($array);
```

Note: This is not for production environments. It needs memory roughly equal to 3 times the file size. @RiggsFolly's solution is much more optimized.